# Resize and select taped UicollectionViewCell with animation

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I want to enlarge all cells, when i tapped on any cell and scroll UICollectionView to this cell with animation.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    fullScreen = !fullScreen;
    [self.photoCollectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
        [self.photoCollectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
    } 
    completion:^(BOOL finished){
         [self.photoCollectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally animated:NO];
     }];
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
   if (fullScreen)
      return CGSizeMake(collectionView.frame.size.width, collectionView.frame.size.height);
   else
      return CGSizeMake(80, 80);
}
```

The problem is that i firstly see first item and then it scrolls to taped item.
And i want to animate resize cell from tapped item.

Comment: Did you find any workaround? @Матвей Козин